# How to find installation of apache

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-20.04, nextcloud

I have a server running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa).  It is at IP address 192.168.1.12

When I use a web browser to access 192.168.1.12, a NextCloud login appears.  This is all well and good except that I have not (purposely) installed NextCloud.  When I connect to port 80 using telnet:

When I connect to the server via telnet on port 80 for more information:

```
> telnet 192.168.1.12 80
Trying 192.168.1.12...
Connected to 192.168.1.12.
Escape character is '^]'.
head / http/1.0
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Mon, 14 Mar 2022 17:24:15 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Length: 226
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
</body></html>
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

When I run apt list --installed, there is no reference to nextcloud and no reference to apache:

```
> apt list --installed | egrep -i 'apache|next'

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

dennis@r2d2:/etc/init.d   03/14 13:26:49
```

Looking in /etc I don't see any folder named apache2 (or similar) and no folder named similarly to nextcloud.

So I'm confused as to how this is all working.  How can I identify the location of the webserver and begin taking control of what it offers?

lsof (thanks, @djdomi) shows the following:

```
root@r2d2:~# netstat -anp | grep apache
root@r2d2:~# lsof -i :80
COMMAND       PID USER   FD   TYPE    DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
Plex\x20M     834 plex   62u  IPv4 158905392      0t0  TCP r2d2.lovelady.com:56860->ec2-52-16-11-44.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:http (CLOSE_WAIT)
Plex\x20T    1670 plex   75u  IPv4     32467      0t0  TCP r2d2.lovelady.com:50452->ec2-18-203-176-12.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:http (CLOSE_WAIT)
httpd     1358151 root    3u  IPv4 157704069      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     1358153 root    3u  IPv4 157704069      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     1358154 root    3u  IPv4 157704069      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     1358155 root    3u  IPv4 157704069      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     2958297 root    3u  IPv4 157704069      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

Again thanks to @djdomi I ran the following command; looks like Plex may be the culprit I'm looking for, but still no real answer to the original question:

```
root@r2d2:/etc/init.d# ps auxwww |egrep '834|1670'
plex         834  0.2  0.3 118780 75268 ?        Ssl  Jan31 131:48 /usr/lib/plexmediaserver/Plex Media Server
plex        1670  0.0  0.0  42192 12528 ?        Sl   Jan31  51:51 /usr/lib/plexmediaserver/Plex Tuner Service /usr/lib/plexmediaserver/Resources/Tuner/Private /usr/lib/plexmediaserver/Resources/Tuner/Shared 1.24.2.4973-2b1b51db9 32600
```

The paths shown just contain a bunch of .ini files.

Comment: you may want to use `lsof -i :80` remind that it can aldo run as a container like socker or lxc

Comment: Thanks @djdomi - lsof (when logged in as root) returns several lines - among them are references to Plex\x20M and Plex\x20T ... but nothing that helps me understand the location of Apache.  I've added the results to the question.

Comment: look for pid 834,1670 you can use `ps auxwww` for it

Comment: Thanks again @djdomi - updated again.

Comment: dennis, how many hints do you need more? :P use apt now for this. This site is for Professional Users. Some help to identify a problem but you should be able to identify a program that is installed. remins that apt-file is also a nice helper ;)

Comment: @djdomi - Please define "Professional Users." If it means someone who already knows everything, then the purpose of the site in the first place, is a matter of question.  I'm sorry that I don't (know everything) --- I don't see enough information in this interaction to determine THE LOCATION OF APACHE or whatever web server is running.  I do know that PLEX is installed - that was not the question.

Comment: ok, the lazy way: `apt install apt-file && apt-file update && apt-file search /usr/lib/plexmediaserver/` This site is for Business Administrators or running a Business. Home and Enduser has to use superuser.com, that is what it it meaned

Comment: @djdomi Gotcha.  I will request closing of this question of possible, and ask again on superuser.  StackOverflow's recent influx of single-purpose servers has more than just me confused.  Having said that, thank you very much (mean it) for the hints and your attention and some guidance.

Comment: you just need to flag it for movement ;) however, you will find with the commands above the package name for removing - and  even its offtopic you get a +1 from me ;)

Comment: Actually, what I found is that that command tries to install more stufff.... libapt-pkg-perl libexporter-tiny-perl liblist-moreutils-perl libregexp-assemble-perl and apt-file libapt-pkg-perl libexporter-tiny-perl liblist-moreutils-perl libregexp-assemble-perl  Thanks though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134766/discussion-between-djdomi-and-dennis).